# Can I use an existing user as Django admin when enabling admin for the first time?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have built a Django site for a while, but I never enabled Django admin.

User accounts are registered on both LDAP and Django, but the master record is based on LDAP. So I must use the account in LDAP as super user.

When I enable Django Admin, I am prompted to create a super user. Can I use an existing account (registered on both LDAP and Django db) as super user?

How?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, but you'll do it through the Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then fetch your user from the database:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username="myname")
user.is_staff = True
user.is_admin = True
user.save()
```

Exit the shell, and that user will now be an admin user.

You can also add the line

```
user.is_superuser = True
```

before calling `user.save()` if you want or need this user to be a superuser and have all the available permissions.

Comment: You are saying skip the user creating part? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can skip that part if you already have a user you want to use.

Comment: It works! However, after getting logged in the admin page, it says "You don't have permission to edit anything.". Is it necessary to modify anything in the apps?

Comment: Ok, I had to add the line `user.is_superuser = True` to get permissions.

Comment: Actually, the `user.is_admin = True` line is doing nothing as the `is_admin` property doesn't exist in the generic User model, the correct line is `user.is_superuser = True`

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer generated an error on Django 3:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'
```

From Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Run this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(username="myname")
user.is_staff = True
user.is_admin = True
user.is_superuser = True
user.save()
```